# Autocomplete is not working on Dynamically Created Rows

Tags: php, javascript

I want to add rows dynamically all rows must have unique id and auto suggest here my code. Unfortunately its not working.

i have following results

1. Dynamically add rows.
2. Autosuggest for all test box dynamically added.
3. unique id for all dynamically added elements.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function()
   {
   var currentItem = 1;

   $('#itemCode_1').autocomplete({
   source: 'data/item-data.php',
   minLength: 1,
   select: function(event, ui) {
       var $itemrow = $(this).closest('tr');

               $itemrow.find('#itemCode_1').val(ui.item.itemCode);
               $itemrow.find('#itemDesc_1').val(ui.item.itemDesc);
               $itemrow.find('#itemPrice_1').val(ui.item.itemPrice);


               $('#itemQty_1').focus();

       return false;
   }

   }).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
   return $( "<li></li>" )
       .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
       .append( "<a>" + item.itemCode + " - " + item.itemDesc + "</a>" )
       .appendTo( ul );
   };



   $('#addRow').click(function(){
       currentItem++;
       var strToAdd = '<tr class="item-row"><td></td><td><input name="itemCode[]" value="" class="tInput" id="itemCode_'+currentItem+'" tabindex="1"/> </td><td><input name="itemDesc[]" value="" class="tInput" id="itemDesc_'+currentItem+'"  readonly="readonly" /></td><td><input name="itemQty[]" value="" class="tInput" id="itemQty_'+currentItem+'" onChange="calc('+currentItem+')" tabindex="2"/></td><td><input name="itemPrice[]" value="" class="tInput" id="itemPrice_'+currentItem+'" onChange="calc('+currentItem+')"/> </td><td> <input type="text" name="sub_total" id="sub_total_'+currentItem+'"></td></tr>';

       $('#itemsTable').append(strToAdd);



   });
   var bindfield=$('itemCode_'+currentItem+'');
       var itemdes=$('#itemDesc_'+currentItem+'');
       var itempr=$('#itemPrice_'+currentItem+'');
       var itemqty=$('#itemQty_'+currentItem+'');
   bindfield.each(function(){
       $(this).autocomplete({
       source: 'data/item-data.php',
       minLength: 1,
       select: function( event, ui ) {             
            var $itemrow = $(this).closest('tr');

               $itemrow.find(bindfield).val(ui.item.itemCode);
               $itemrow.find(itemdes).val(ui.item.itemDesc);
               $itemrow.find(itempr).val(ui.item.itemPrice);


               $(itemqty).focus();

       return false;
       }
   });
       })
   $('#itemCode').focus(function(){
   window.onbeforeunload = function(){ return "You haven't saved your data.  Are you sure you want to leave this page without saving first?"; };
   });

   });
   ```

Comment: not working means how to which instinct it is working expalin in detail

Comment: i can able to add dynamically rows and first rows auto complete is working fine but the other rows which we dynamically adding for that auto complete is not working

Comment: It looks like you almost straight copied http://www.codemashups.com/jquerys-autocomplete-using-multiple-inputs-in-same-table/ and tried to do, not sure what with it other than adding unique id's?  I see that you have added a function to do `calc` in there, but don't give us that function to work with as well.  I would suggest making a JSFiddle with what you have so we might see all of what you have - though change to a local source for the JSFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You can give the class name instead of giving the ID,  by giving so the autocomplete is applied for all the elements having the Specified Class name..In your code above you can give

**$('.CLASSNAME).autocomplete({   });**

instead of

**$('#itemCode_1').autocomplete({   });**

Give the below code for the dynamically created elements to work.

$('.CLASSNAME').live('keydown.autocomplete', function() {

```
       // Write your code to initiate the autocomplete
```

});

Make the same class name for the dynamically created elements...
Hope this will work try this...

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var counter =2;
    var count=2;
    $("#addmember").click(function () {     
        $('#member').append('<input type="text" name="member' +counter+ '" id="member' + counter + '">');
        counter++;
        jQuery("#member" +count+ "").autocomplete('Your Url', {
            multiple: false,
            matchContains: true,
            width: 180,
            selectFirst: true,
        });
        jQuery("#member" +count+ "").result(function(event, data, formatted) {

            count++;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

this is in header part and in body

```
<input name="member1" id="member1" type="text" />
<div id="member"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks For your help its works, but now i stuck in another problem, its works normally to add texbox dynamically but when we edit the previous textbox its not working to populate the value. my code goes like this
 jQuery("#member" +count+ "").autocomplete('get_course_list2.php', {
  multiple: false,
  matchContains: true,
 width: 180,
 selectFirst: true,
        });
        jQuery("#member" +count+ "").result(function(event, data, formatted) {
var tempcount=counter-1;
alert(count);
alert(data[1]);
$("#price" + count + "").val(data[1]);
count++;  });

Comment: thanks for your response. please check like this, first add 3 or more text box with value after that alter the previous one, here in this case we can get the autosuggestion but but its fail to change the value that we stored in item price. then try to add another text box there no autosuggestion comes again add another one works smooth.  hope i shared it correct if u don't mind may i have get your communication email id, mine is ameer@woolpack.in